# sqlldr issue with copying a certain table

Tags: oracle, oracle10g, sql-loader

I have 4 tables I am copying from one schema to another using sqldr. 3 of the tables gave me no issues and I was able to successfully copy them all over. The 4th is where my problem arises. I cant quite understand why, there is nothing special about this 4th table as far as data types go or anything else. When i do run the sqlldr command, all rows end up in the .bad file and none are copied over. I will list the code im using for better understanding.

```
> pico deptbb02.csv
   UW PICO(tm) 4.10                                                     File: deptbb02.csv

10,infield,Jade,Clairmont,Lets play two
20,outfield,House of Pasta,Santee,Alea iacta est
30,pitcher,Crab Shack,Pacific Beach,Semper paratus
40,staff,Burger King,Lakeside,Experientia docet
50,catchers,Pinnacle Peak,Santee,Non Bastardi Carborundum

   UW PICO(tm) 4.10                                                     File: deptload.ctl

LOAD DATA
infile 'deptbb02.csv'
replace into table deptbb02
fields terminated by ','
(DEPTNO,DNAME,RESTAURANT,LOCATION,MOTTO)


> sqlldr username/password@database

control = deptload.ctl

SQL*Loader: Release 10.2.0.1.0 - Production on Tue Jul 28 01:27:38 2015

Copyright (c) 1982, 2005, Oracle.  All rights reserved.

Commit point reached - logical record count 6
```

TABLE deptbb02 defined as...

```
SQL> desc deptbb02
 Name                                      Null?    Type
 ----------------------------------------- -------- ----------------------------
 DEPTNO                                             NUMBER(3)
 DNAME                                              VARCHAR2(8)
 RESTAURANT                                         VARCHAR2(15)
 LOCATION                                           VARCHAR2(15)
 MOTTO                                              VARCHAR2(30)
```

I think this should be everything needed to understand my question, but don't hesitate to ask if i missed something. Thanks!

Comment: Please post the error messages from the .log file.

Comment: I'm going to go out on a limb and say the problem is the lack of TRAILING NULLCOLS specified in the ctl file.  But the log should clue us in.

Comment: Record 6: Rejected - Error on table DEPTBB02, column DEPTNO.
Column not found before end of logical record (use TRAILING NULLCOLS)
Record 1: Rejected - Error on table DEPTBB02, column MOTTO.
ORA-12899: value too large for column "ST101"."DEPTBB02"."MOTTO" (actual: 54, maximum: 30)

Record 2: Rejected - Error on table DEPTBB02, column MOTTO.
ORA-12899: value too large for column "ST101"."DEPTBB02"."MOTTO" (actual: 46, maximum: 30)

Record 3: Rejected - Error on table DEPTBB02, column MOTTO.
ORA-12899: value too large for column "ST101"."DEPTBB02"."MOTTO" (actual: 44, maximum: 30)

Answer (score 0):

I suspect the data has spaces or control characters at the end of the MOTTO column or the sample data you posted is not the same as what was attempted to load in the .log file.  i.e.

```
Record 3: Rejected - Error on table DEPTBB02, column MOTTO. ORA-12899: value too large for column "ST101"."DEPTBB02"."MOTTO" (actual: 44, maximum: 30)
```

The MOTTO column is defined in the table as varchar2(30) but sqlldr sees 44 characters.  The data as shown for the 3rd record is 14 characters.  Open the data file in an editor that can show control characters and spaces.

Try putting a TRIM() call around the fields in the control file to remove leading and trailing spaces maybe:

```
LOAD DATA
infile 'deptbb02.csv'
replace into table deptbb02
fields terminated by ','
(DEPTNO,
DNAME,
RESTAURANT,
LOCATION,
MOTTO    CHAR  "TRIM(:MOTTO)"
)
```